# Kubectl GKE PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Folks, when running the following kubectl command:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: openvpn-data-claim
  namespace: openvpn
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

```
error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v1.Scale): invalid object doesn't have additional properties
```

kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.9-gke.24", GitCommit:"39e41a8d6b7221b901a95d3af358dea6994b4a40", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-29T01:24:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 2):

- This answer is is an addition to @Cmag answer and
  my intention is to provide more insights about this issue to help the community.

According to Kubernetes **[Version Skew Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl):**

> `kubectl` is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of `kube-apiserver`.
>
> **IF** `kube-apiserver` is at **1.15**: `kubectl` is supported at **1.16**, **1.15**, and **1.14**.
>
> **Note:** If version skew exists between kube-apiserver instances in an HA cluster, for example `kube-apiserver` instances are at **1.15** and **1.14**, `kubectl` will support only **1.15** and **1.14** since any other versions would be more than one minor version skewed.

- Each update of kubernetes has many components that are added, changed, moved, deprecated or removed. Here is the [Kubernetes Changelog of version 1.15](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md).

**Even running a much newer client versions may give you some issues**

- In K8s 1.10 the `kubectl run` had a default behavior of creating deployments:

```
❯ ./kubectl-110 run ubuntu --image=ubuntu          
deployment.apps "ubuntu" created
```

- Starting on 1.12 the `kubectl run` was [deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68132) to all generators except pods, here is an example with **kubectl 1.16**:

```
❯ ./kubectl-116 run ubuntu --image=ubuntu --dry-run
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/ubuntu created (dry run)
```

- Besides the warning, it still work as intended, but it [changed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87077) in K8s 1.18 client:

```
❯ ./kubectl-118 version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:56:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.9-gke.24", GitCommit:"39e41a8d6b7221b901a95d3af358dea6994b4a40", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-29T01:24:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 ubuntu --image=ubuntu --dry-run=client
Flag --generator has been deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future.
pod/ubuntu created (dry run)
```

It ignored the flag and created only a pod. That flag is supported by kubernetes 1.15 as we saw in the test, but the kubectl 1.18 had significant changes that did not allowed running it.

- This is a simple example to illustrate the importance to follow the skew policy on Kubernetes, it can save a lot of troubleshooting time in the future!

Comment: Good stuff, thank you!.  Yet another reason why to use asdf version managed kubectl so you can have several readily available managing different k8s clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Easily fixed by upgrading local kubectl with asdf.

```
asdf install kubectl 1.15.9
```